# Archive only for /year/month, not terms

Tags: templates, archives

I want archive template to be used when I visit `/year/month`, for example `/2018/04`.

But I don't want the archive template to be used for terms. For example: `/tag/news` or `/countries/sweden`.

How do I do this?

Comment: You only want exactly for `/year/month` for the `post` post type and not e.g.  `/year` ?

Comment: @birgire No for year as well. Just not for terms.

Comment: Did you try `date.php` ? See template hierarchy [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).